# How to enable NTFS folder compression on Windows Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-core

I want to enable NTFS compression on a specific folder, in my case: `C:\inetpub\logs`.

This is easily done in Windows Server with Desktop Experience, but in Server Core how this can be achieved?

To be precise I just want the equivalent of checking the box "Compress contents to save disk space".

[image: NTFS Folder Compression]

Comment: As an alternative, you could write a utility to zip up all the logs for a month and perhaps migrate them to yearly folders, and run it as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [compact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/compact) utility that can change compression attribute from the command line. For example to set compression for the `c:\docs` directory and all files in it:

```
> compact /c /s:c:\docs *
```

A good description of the `compact` command is here:
[Compressing a File or Folder](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-server-cookbook/0596006330/ch04s15.html)

You should be aware of the limitations of NTFS compression before deciding to use it. Please see [Understanding NTFS Compression](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/05/20/understanding-ntfs-compression/).

Comment: Thanks! With this command, new created files will be automatically compressed too?

Comment: Yes, the new files created in the directory and its subdirectories later on will be compressed also